# Regexp: only match word if it doesn't start with a dot

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Lets say I have this string:

> key something.key() (.key)(key)

I would like regex to only match the word "keys" that are inside "[ ]"

> [key] something.key() (.key)([key])

I have used this regex currently /(?!\.)key/g

But that only excludes dot and still selects word even if it startet with a dot.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I only want to match the word "word" so not the word "something". I'll edit the post to make it more clear

Comment: What about: (^|[^\.])(key)

Comment: Problem is that it also matches "(key" while I want it to only match "key"

Comment: If you take group(2) it will only match "key"

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ZTU63W/2/

Comment: How do I take group(2) in javascript? Sorry I havn't heard about this technique before

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative character class to match *not a dot*:

`[^\.]`

Then add `^` to match *not a dot* **or** at *the beginning of the string*:

`([^\.]|^)`

Add `?:` to the group to make it non-capturing.

`(?:[^\.]|^)`

Finally add a capturing group matching your word:

`(?:[^\.]|^)(word)`

You could achieve the same result using negative look-behind:

`(?<!\.)word`

Alas, JavaScript regex doesn’t implement it.

Comment: This is a step forward but it also creates another problem I also encountered: The regex (?:[^\.]|^)(word) will select "(word" as a match, I would like it to only select "word". Or if a string contains "/word" then regex will select the whole "/word" and not just  "word".

Comment: That’s why "word" is in a capturing group. Don’t use the whole match. Use the first capturing group — it won’t include the character before “word”.

Comment: Here’s a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ft2o3apL/6/